# Ensure the POST data is valid JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

I am developping a JSON API with Python Flask.
What I want is to always return JSON, with a error message indicating any error that occured.

That API also only accept JSON data in the POST body, but Flask by default return a HTML error 400 if it can't read the data as JSON.

Preferably, I d also like to not force the user to send the `Content-Type` header, and if `raw` or `text` content-type, try to parse the body as JSON nonetheless.

In short, I need a way to validate that the POST body's is JSON, and handle the error myself.

I've read about adding decorator to `request` to do that, but no comprehensive example.

Comment: You can just ask for the get_json method on the request as said here with force=True https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json, if it returns None, aka if not request.get_json() you just then fire an error or let it raise a 400

Comment: @lapinkoira: that method raises a `BadRequest` exception when called, unless you set `silent=True`.

Comment: No it wont if as OP said there is not content type application json "By default this function will return None if the mimetype is not application/json"

Comment: @lapinkoira @Martijn Pieters: Combining `force=True` and `silent=True` does make `request.get_json` return `None` on wrong or no data, and answer what I need, I ll look at @Martijn Pieters solution, but I have a working solution now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three options:

- Register a [custom error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) for 400 errors on the API views. Have this error return JSON instead of HTML.
- Set the [`Request.on_json_loading_failed` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Request.on_json_loading_failed) to something that raises a [`BadRequest` exception](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest) subclass with a JSON payload. See [*Custom Errors*](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/exceptions/#custom-errors) in the Werkzeug exceptions documentation to see how you can create one.
- Put a `try: except` around the `request.get_json()` call, catch the `BadRequest` exception and raise a new exception with a JSON payload.

Personally, I'd probably go with the second option:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest
from flask import json, Request, _request_ctx_stack


class JSONBadRequest(BadRequest):
    def get_body(self, environ=None):
        """Get the JSON body."""
        return json.dumps({
            'code':         self.code,
            'name':         self.name,
            'description':  self.description,
        })

    def get_headers(self, environ=None):
        """Get a list of headers."""
        return [('Content-Type', 'application/json')]


def on_json_loading_failed(self):
    ctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
    if ctx is not None and ctx.app.config.get('DEBUG', False):
        raise JSONBadRequest('Failed to decode JSON object: {0}'.format(e))
    raise JSONBadRequest()


Request.on_json_loading_failed = on_json_loading_failed
```

Now, every time `request.get_json()` fails, it'll call your custom `on_json_loading_failed` method and raise an exception with a JSON payload rather than a HTML payload.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the options `force=True` and `silent=True` make the result of `request.get_json` be `None` if the data is not parsable, then a simple `if` allow you to check the parsing.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def function(function = None):
    print "Data: ", request.get_json(force = True, silent = True);
    if request.get_json() is not None:
        return "Is JSON";
    else:
        return "Nope";

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Credits to lapinkoira and Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decode JSON object using python json library. 
The main idea is to take plain request body and try to convert to JSON.E.g:

```
import json
...
# somewhere in view
def view():
    try:
        json.loads(request.get_data())
    except ValueError:
        # not a JSON! return error
        return {'error': '...'}
    # do plain stuff
```